# Initialize class as another class

Tags: python, oop

I'd like to do some sort of "reversed inheritance", in which I have a class that is initialized as another class, according to input, and has several shared methods as well. I'm not interested in instantiating a different classes for each input, I'd like that to happen 'under the hood'.
I'm looking for the correct way to do the following:

```
class Carpenter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tools = ['saw', 'screwdriver']
        self.material = 'wood'

class Baker():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tools = ['oven', 'mixer']
        self.material = 'flour'

class Professional():
    def __init__(self, profession, name):
        self.name = name
        if profession == 'carpenter':
            Carpenter.__init__(self)
        elif profession == 'baker':
            Baker.__init__(self)

    def work(self):
        print('working')

    def go_home(self):
        print('finally')
```

I could do it by performing 'by-the-book' inheritance and calling a function to handle the input-dependent logic:

```
class Professional():
    ...

class Carpenter(Professional):
    ...

class Baker(Professional):
    ...

def get_professional(profession):
    if profession == 'baker':
        professional = Baker()
    elif profession == 'carpenter':
        professional = Carpenter()
    return professional
```

However I've been wondering if there's a more elegant way to do so.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a case for composition or a factory function, not inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use a dictionary:

```
professional = {'baker': Baker, 'carpenter': Carpenter}
```

then use;

```
def get_professional(profession):
    constructor = professional['profession']
    return constructor()
```

Another way would use the exec function but it would not be a good idea

Comment: Your code assumes that you need exact one Baker and one Carpenter so you create them before `get_professional` is called. This assumption might not hold true and the user might want to obtain a new instance everything it calls `get_professional`.

Comment: It is perfectly true, I think my solution is better now ?